# Convert To Dictionary in Robot Framework gives the error "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework

I cannot seem to find any examples for the Convert To Dictionary keyword so I am not really sure on how to use it.

The following code:

```
 ${newdomain_dict}                 Convert To Dictionary   {'id': 'newdomain', 'entityTypes': ['users', 'msg', 'xmpp']}
```

gives the error "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

The documentation just says this keyword has one argument (item), so I am not sure what this "item" is meant to be - I assumed a string. Even when I looked on github at the source code this is the impression I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the argument `{'id': 'newdomain', 'entityTypes': ['users', 'msg', 'xmpp']}` is treated as a string.

The documentation for that keyword says this:

> Mainly useful for converting other mappings to normal dictionaries.

A string is not a mapping type.

If you're wanting to define a dictionary via a string, you can use robot's [inline python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id117).

```
${newdomain_dict}  ${{ {'id': 'newdomain', 'entityTypes': ['users', 'msg', 'xmpp']} }}
```